# Color of errobar different from the graph matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, errorbar

i have this problem i want to make a color of errobars different from the color of my graph 
there is the code i have tried

```
pp=errorbar(x,testMatriceFluxSortie/ValeurFluxSortie(1,1),err)
pp.Color=[255 0 1]./255;
```

But it gives me this all in red 
[my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWmm4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always use `hold on` and plot only the x,y data after the errorbar was plotted, for example:

```
x = 1:10:100;
y = [20 30 45 40 60 65 80 75 95 90];
err = 8*ones(size(y));

errorbar(x,y,err,'or'); hold on
plot(x,y,'b');
```

[image]