# How to set the errorbars in a different color from the plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

When making a plot in Matlab using `errorbar(...)` the color of the error bars is the same as the plot. How do I set them to be in a different color?

I tried looking for a way to do it in here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.errorbar-properties.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html

But I couldn't find it.

Edit: This question:
[Color of errobar different from the graph matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501431/color-of-errobar-different-from-the-graph-matlab) 
doesn't have the answer to what I'm asking. It was asked almost a year and half ago and no solution was given. The one comment there doesn't give a proper solution. It says to draw the plot twice - once with the errorbars (when the plot and the errorbars are at the same color) and a second time just the plot without the errorbars (which will be drawn on top of the first one using hold on). There should be a way to draw the figure once with the errorbars at a different color than the color of the plot - that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color of errobar different from the graph matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501431/color-of-errobar-different-from-the-graph-matlab)

Comment: @PhilGoddard I havn't seen that one when I searched. Looking at it now - it was asked almost a year and half ago and no solution was given. The one comment there doesn't give a proper solution. It says to draw the plot twice - once with the errorbars (when the plot and the errorbars are at the same color) and a second time just the plot without the errorbars (which will be drawn on top of the first one using hold on). There should be a way to draw the figure once with the errorbars at a different color than the color of the plot - that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: that is what the asker of the duplicate question wants too.  I believe the answer given is still the only viable approach.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Yes, but that was a year and a half ago and no proper solution was given. I was sure there was a simple way to draw an errorbar plot with the error bars being at a different color than the plot, that is why I asked the question. It is quite strange that there isn't and the only way to get it is to draw the plot twice.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you can save a graphical object by storing the output of a plotting function. And then try to `set` the color of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty implementation of a function that allows to style the errorbars and the data separatly. However, internally it does the same as the answers to the previously posted question: it uses two plots.

```
function varargout = mc_errorbar(ax, x,y,e, varargin)
% MC_ERRORBAR   errorbar which allows to style errorbar and data separately
%
% Usage:
%   mc_errorbar(X,Y,E) 
%     plots errorbars and a separate line in the current axis. 
%
%   mc_errorbar(X,Y,E, property, value)
%     plots errorbars and a separate line in the current axis and styles
%     the plots according to the properties given. All properties that are
%     accepted by the errorbar function are allowed, but should be prefixed
%     with 'EB'. Note that the LineStyle property will be overriden.
%     Properties not prefixed with 'EB' will be passed to the plot
%     function, hence all properties allowed by plot are allowed here, too.
%
%   mc_errorbar(ax, ___) 
%     plots in the axes ax instead of the current axes.
%     
%   [lh] = mc_errorbar(___) 
%     returns the line handle
%
%   [lh, ebh] = mc_errorbar(___)
%     returns the line handle and the handle to the errorbar
%
% See also errorbar plot

    if ~isa(ax, 'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes')
        if nargin > 3
            varargin = [{e}, varargin(:)'];
        end

        e = y;
        y = x;
        x = ax;
        ax = gca();
    end
    oldnextplot = ax.NextPlot;
    ebargs = {};
    lineargs = {};
    for k = 1:2:numel(varargin)
        if strcmp(varargin{k}(1:2),'EB') == 1
            ebargs{end+1} = varargin{k}(3:end);
            ebargs{end+1} = varargin{k+1};
        else
            lineargs{end+1} = varargin{k};
            lineargs{end+1} = varargin{k+1};
        end
    end
    ebargs{end+1} = 'LineStyle';
    ebargs{end+1} = 'none';
    eb = errorbar(ax, x, y, e, ebargs{:});
    ax.NextPlot = 'add';
    line = plot(ax, x,y, lineargs{:});
    ax.NextPlot = oldnextplot;
    if nargout > 0
        varargout{1} = line;
    end
    if nargout > 1
        varargout{2} = eb;
    end

end
```

Example:

```
mc_errorbar(1:10, (1:10)*2, (1:10)*.5, 'Color','g', 'EBColor', 'k', 'EBLineWidth', 3, 'LineStyle','-', 'LineWidth',8)
```

[image]